# What is netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-launcher

I'm trying to download Minecraft again, and I get this in the download bar of the launcher: `Downloading netty-all-4.0.23.Final.ja`r. Can someone tell me what that means?

Oh and it's either that or this right here: `Downloading twitch-external-platform-4.5-natives-windows-32.jar`. The reason I'm doing this is because I get those message in the download bar and nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

[Netty](http://netty.io/) is a Java framework for event-driven networking.

The other JAR (Java archive) is the Twitch client API for Java.

Comment: Ok, and can you tell me why is stay frozen in the download bar and nothing happens.

Comment: ... Probably because it's taking a while to download it for some reason.

Comment: So I have to wait for it to download?

Comment: That would be my guess. If you still see no progress after a little while then I would ask for help on the official forums, since they may be experiencing server issues.